Need help in installation of opencv4nodejs
I am trying to install opencv4nodejs but I keep getting a error :
 Node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1185 return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
using node version 16.4.0 tried using the autobuild disable option but still the problem persist. I then tried to manually build it using choco opencv command and set the directory but after the package was built I get this error
Can anyone recommend me a solution
